# Freeform Pro - AJAX response information not being returned

Tags: solspace-freeform, ajax, aws

We have recently moved server to the AWS platform so this might be an issue on the infrastructure side of things rather than with Freeform Pro.

However I have a modal contact us form that is being submitted by AJAX. The data is being saved to Freeform but I'm not getting any kind of AJAX response data when I take a look in Chrome Dev Tools.

Could this be an issue with using a load balancer?

Comment: Can you share your freeform tag, version numbers and server setup (you mention a load balancer) with us too please?

Answer (score 0):

There's no easy answer here I'm afraid.

Becasue the freeform entry is created we can assume that the ACTion request is processed and a response is "trying" to be sent, it's just you're not recieving it. This in turn leads us to the question "Where is my response going?"

First step for me would be to run a test and check your server logs (apache? whats your hosting enviroment??), this will confirm that a response is being sent from the server at least...

If you can re-test without your load balancer / server cache that would be great.

However in lieu of this lets start by confirming if a plain old AJAX works...

One template, really simple for this example it'll be located at `test/is_it_safe`, the contents :

```
{"answer":"yes it is"}
```

Then on another page (lets say `test/ajax`) lets stick a simple Jquery script...

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(e){
    $.ajax("index.php/test/is_it_safe", {
        dataType: 'JSON',
        success: function(data) {
            alert("Is it safe? " + data.answer);
        }}
    );
});
</script>
```

Load the page, does the answer get returned?? YOu can also expand on your test script (add an error: handler, add some console.logs ect) to see if the response is malformed/not coming/ect....